# Sending N amount of Requests at the same time every N seconds in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-requests, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to build an HTTP Request Load Generator in Python. It needs to send an N amount, 10K max, of requests every X seconds. I believe that requires me to have an N amount of timers. I do not know where to really start since there are so many libraries I could possibly use like threading, asyncio, gevent, grequests, locust, twisted, etc. Since there will be times were some requests will need to be sent at the same time.

I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: linux's crontab might be handy, but it doesn't support sub-minute intervals.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you include some attempt that you've made to do it yourself. You could just pick one of the libs you mentioned and start working from there, and ask a question whenever you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of all the ones you've mentioned,

- locust - Scalable user load testing tool written in Python.

And,

- eventlet - Asynchronous framework with WSGI support.
- gevent - A coroutine-based Python networking library that uses
  greenlet.
- multiprocessing - (Python standard library) Process-based "threading"
  interface.
- threading - (Python standard library) Higher-level threading
  interface.
- Tomorrow - Magic decorator syntax for asynchronous code.
- uvloop - Ultra fast implementation of asyncio event loop on top of
  libuv.

As quoted [here](https://awesome-python.com/).

A little bit of surfing through(like the [good and bad](https://engineering.mixpanel.com/2010/10/29/gevent-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/) and [discussion like this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gevent/TelwPl3KgnE)), suggested that gevent seems little better when compared to other libraries.

Hope this helps!